# Remove pseudo duplicates pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with four columns 'id1', 'id2', 'info1' and 'info2'.
I want to remove duplicates not only in the classical sense but also if id1 and id2 are exchanged.

Example:

'Joe', 'Jane', 1.2, 'Blue'

and

'Jane', 'Joe', 1.2, 'Blue'

must be regarded as duplicates.

id1 and id2 can be of any type, not only integer, float, or string.

Comment: Do your pseudo duplicates have exactly the same contents in info1 and info2 clumns? If so, just use those two to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the `ids` and then call `drop_duplicates`:

```
df[['id1', 'id2']] = np.sort(df[['id1', 'id2']], axis=1)
df.drop_duplicates(['id1', 'id2'])
```

Comment: What if the id objects are not sortable?

Comment: @Aristodog They better be, or else there's no point to your question

Comment: Some objects can be compared (equal or different) but there may not be a natural order (so they cannot be sorted). Can we proceed without sort?

Comment: @Aristodog If they can be compared, that's enough for `np.sort` to work, because it will sort all pairs the _same way_, regardless of whether that order is to your liking or not. That's why this should work. Did you try it at least? What errors do you get?